# Inverses of the sums of all possible subsets of a set of symmetric and positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a set of $c$ matrices $A_1 ... A_c$ which are all symmetric and positive definite. I would like to calculate the inverses of all the possible sums, i.e.

$(A_1+A_2)^{-1},(A_1+A_3)^{-1},(A_2+A_3)^{-1},(A_1+A_2+A_3)^{-1}$

My main limitation is memory, i.e. I don't want to store the $2^c$ inverses, but find a way given a limited number of inverses to be able to compute the inverse I want from those I stored.

To go a bit farther, the matrices will be continuously updated using  rank-one updates. Thus I would like to compute the rank-one updates of a limited subset of these $2^c$ inverses and be able to compute the inverse I want in $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Absent some special properties, such as commutativity of the various $A_i$'s, I don't know of any way to do what you propose.

Comment: I feel curious to know the application of this. Is it some kind of filter design?

Comment: Are you looking for the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula)?